# Continue the loop after receiving any error

Tags: javascript, node.js

below is the cycle we start with

// SKU - stock keeping unit

```
const name = ["shoes", "hoodies", "trousers"] //for example, these are the names of our products

const ProductSKU = await GetProductSKUFromApi(name) // for each product, for example shoes, returns several SKU

        const length = Object.keys(ProductSKU).length // Here we check the number of SKU

            for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
                try {
                    const SKU = ProductSKU[i]["sku"] // each time we get the SKU, one by one
                    console.log(SKU) // Just to understand which SKU is checked in this cycle
                    const ProductInfo = await GetAllProductInfo(SKU) // Passing the SKU to get data on it
                    console.log(ProductInfo) //Getting information about a product

                }   catch (error) {
                      console.log(error)
                }
        }
```

> **The problem is -:**

if const ProductInfo = await GetAllProductInfo(SKU), some error (any) occurs in the
GetAllProductInfo(SKU) function, then the cycle is completely
interrupted instead of moving to the next SKU.

> **Question -:**

How can I make the cycle continue from the next SKU after receiving an error?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of the error in the GetAllProductInfo(SKU) function, the only reasonable solution was to do a try - catch

You need to find the problem area in the function and do as in the example below

this code is also inside return new Promise - for this, resolve is used below and json which it should return if there are empty values

```
const JsonFromHtml = []

    try {
        JsonFromHtml.push(
        root.querySelector('#Some_Selector).
        getAttribute('Some_Attribute'))
    } catch (e) {

          let json_response = {
              "rating": 0,
              "reviews": 0,
              "delivery date": "",
               "stocks": "",
          } 

          resolve(json_response)  
          
          }


//  the rest of the code will be executed if the condition is met
```

> thanks to this, the loop is not interrupted and, on error, simply
> returns empty data, since such products do not exist